# R create a dataframe with discrete steps based on a range?

Tags: r

Hi supposed I have a `range from 0-112` and I want to create a dataframe with steps= 20,
for example, ideally I can set `step =20` and it would return,

```
V1 V2
0  20
20 40
40 60
60 80
80 100
100 112
```

I can do this with a loop and built the dataframe row by row until it reaches the max, but wondering if there is a more efficient/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq` to create the first vector, then remove the first element from the vector while concatenating the 112 at the end to create the second vector and then construct the `data.frame` with the two vectors

```
V1 <- seq(0, 112, by = 20)
V2 <- c(V1[-1], 112)
data.frame(V1, V2)
```

-output

```
   V1  V2
1   0  20
2  20  40
3  40  60
4  60  80
5  80 100
6 100 112
```

---

Or in a single step

```
within(data.frame(V1 = 0:5 * 20), V2 <- c(V1[-1], 112))
   V1  V2
1   0  20
2  20  40
3  40  60
4  60  80
5  80 100
6 100 112
```